# recover myfile.py following a wrong git operation

Tags: git, undo, recover

I would like to recover myfile.py following a wrong git operation.

This is what I did:

```
git add myfile.py
git checkout 0ddb6x myfile.py (wrong operation, which changed the content myfile.py on my local machine)
made some change on myfile.py
git add myfile.py (wrong operation)
```

Now I hope go go back to myfile.py before checkout. Is it possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+add+checkout+recover

Comment: https://github.com/pendashteh/git-recover-index

Answer (score 0):

So you added the file, then checked it out again.
That checkout should have done nothing, meaning for all intents and purposes, all you did was a `git add`.

By doing another `git add` after making changes, you have added those changes into the *index*, where it records what files look like before committing them.

What are you trying to go back to, exactly? The file on disk can only be reverted to a time before any `git add` commands were issued.